# Are there any "exercises" for your eyes that will help with near or far sightedness?

Tags: medical-science

There are different sites purporting to have exercises that reduce or eliminate the need to wear glasses.   Are there any such exercises that have been proven to work?

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/138/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [abstract](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19154276) of Ophthalmic and Physiological Optics 2009
Jan;29(1):4-25.: "Although there are areas where the available evidence is
consistent with claims made by behavioural optometrists (most notably in
relation to the treatment of convergence insufficiency, the use of yoked
prisms in neurological patients, and in vision rehabilitation after brain
disease/injury), a large majority of behavioural management approaches are
not evidence-based, and thus cannot be advocated."

Even for disorders where exercise does work, doing them yourself at home
may be less efficient then office-based exercise, as [was shown](http://archopht.ama-assn.org/cgi/content/full/126/10/1336) for
treatment for sympotomatic convergence insufficiency in children.

Quackwatch has a [good article](http://www.quackwatch.org/01QuackeryRelatedTopics/eyequack.html) reviewing some eye-related claims. They
end with a warning: "Remember: no type of eye exercise can improve a
refractive error or cure any ailment within the eyeball [...]". If you have
any problems with your eyes, it is best to go see [an eye doctor](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=43039).