# Does eye exercises help improve your eyesight?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine, ophthalmology

I asked the eye doctor if exercises will help my aging vision and he said basically that the benefits of eye exercise are inconclusive. I looked on Skeptics and found that this was discussed 3 years ago in several posts (linked below). One wonders if our understanding has improved over the last three years? Then I looked around the internet for something that looked reliable and found at the American Optometric Association that it helps in the cases of:

> Research has demonstrated vision therapy can be an effective treatment option for:
>
> - Ocular motility dysfunctions (eye movement disorders)
> - Non-strabismic binocular disorders (inefficient eye teaming)
> - Strabismus (misalignment of the eyes)
> - Amblyopia (poorly developed vision)
> - Accommodative disorders (focusing problems)
> - Visual information processing disorders, including visual-motor integration and integration with other sensory modalities

[source](http://www.aoa.org/optometrists/education-and-training/clinical-care/vision-therapy)

The Skeptics research so far is at (3 years old):
[Are there any "exercises" for your eyes that will help with near or far sightedness?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/629/are-there-any-exercises-for-your-eyes-that-will-help-with-near-or-far-sightedn)

[Strange way of improving eyesight -- Could it work?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2482/strange-way-of-improving-eyesight-could-it-work)

So, the question is:
Has our understanding of this subject grown enough since 3 years ago to decide the efficacy of eye exercises?

Comment: This is a duplicate. I will ask a question on meta.skeptics about how we would like to deal with these issues.

Comment: If you would you might also consider that several "old" topics are research/study dependent and science, obviously, is not static. thus, what is true a few years ago may not be accepted today.

Comment: Indeed. I've asked [the community how they would like to deal with this class of question](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2739/are-is-this-still-true-questions-permitted).

Comment: 3 years in Computers is not long (I just bought a 3 terrabyte hard drive for $100) ... 3 years in mathematics is not long (major theorems are being proved) ... 3 years in education is not long (states have gone to common core and some are leaving it). With the internet everything is accelerated anyway.

Comment: @user144668 I'd suggest leaving a comment asking for updates at the old question, or offering a bounty to trigger more attention there.

Comment: @user144668: Sorry, I am not sure what point your last comment is intended to make.

Comment: @Oddthinking it is to state that things do indeed move quite quickly in this age and day.

Comment: Opthamology is neither commodity manufacturing, mathematics, education nor Internet. Your cherry-picked examples don't help, but see the meta-question for more discussion.

Comment: Fine, here we see that developments in ophthamology are published on a yearly basis http://www.karger.com/BookSeries/Home/223974 ... any one else on here with a Masters degree or above should be able to confirm with me that most fields develop on a regular basis except for outdated or irrelevant obscure fields.