# Do colors change your mood?

Tags: psychology, colors

In 2012, the Painters of Louisville published an [infographic about the Psychology of Color](http://paintersoflouisville.com/tag/the-psychology-of-color/):

[image: Infographic]

It makes a number of claims about how seeing certain colors may effects on your mood and physiology. Some examples include:

> Blue: Most productive color.
>   Pink: Calming. Warm
>   Red: Encourages appetite.

Is there any truth to this?

Comment: Closely related (duplicate?) question:  [Does the color red have psychological effects?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/does-the-color-red-have-psychological-effects)

Comment: The reason that we have those more specific questions (there's one on yellow as well) is the this is way too broad. This is for two reasons: different colors might or might not have effects; asking if a color has *any* effect seems to be very open-ended.

Comment: Please restrict this to a single color and a single effect (or a specific, relatively small, set of effects).

Comment: Very strange, then, Sklivvz, that you also voted to close the linked more-specific question.