# Can nearsightedness be cured with yoga?

Tags: ophthalmology, india, yoga

Baba [Ramdev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramdev) claims [in this 1hr Hindi video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=242xu5EWSwg) that yoga can cure myopia.

Is there evidence that one can be cured of myopia by yoga?

Comment: There are several different claims here. Let's restrict the question to one claim. The first link is for the Bates' Method, for which we [already have an answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/138/is-the-bates-method-for-improving-eyesight-efficacious). I think the second link is also the Bates method. The third link has many different claims.

Comment: @Oddthinking I've changed the question altogether. Now it is more of a yes/no type question which can be answered in two lines as _Yes xyz has been found to have cured his myopia_ and _abc company offers a bounty of jkl dollars if myopia is proved to be cured naturally_.

Comment: According to the [FAQ](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), Skeptics.SE is for researching the evidence behind the claims you *hear or read*. This question appears to be *your own* speculation, and is off-topic. Please edit it to reference a claim that other people are making and flag for moderator attention to re-open (or get 5 re-open votes).

Comment: @Oddthinking I don't know what kind of references there could be for a claim that I heard from other people. These claims I heard only in my locality and don't know how to give a reference of those people. At least I can give links to some websites and youtube videos that make similar claims [Link 1](http://www.curejoy.com/content/improve-eyesight-with-ayurveda-herbs-and-home-remedies-for-failing-vision/) [Link 2](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=ramdev+eyes+yoga)

Comment: !!!??? I flagged it and the response is _declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention_

Comment: Your edits didn't improve the question. If anything, they made it even broader. There are now dozens of competing claims here (many different herbs? fruit? homeopathy? 44,000 videos, plus one that is linked where it isn't in English and we don't know what part of the video contains the claim) Please pick one claim, quote it precisely, and we can answer it. No-one seems to be claiming anything about a bounty, so I don't know why that is part of the question.

Comment: @Oddthinking I think you did not read my question contemplatively. First you were saying that _it is your own speculation_. Now you are saying _There are now dozens of competing claims_. My question **was** and **is** that "_Has in medical science it ever found that a human without getting surgery is cured of myopia_?" The people who claim that myopia is cured are Indian and speak Hindi and I gave links to them. Now I am giving only one reference.

Comment: The whole video claims only one thing "_Curing eye-sight_", in technical sense cure of _myopia_ and _hyper myopia_. I don't say check that particular claim or a particular yoga technique. I just want to know that is any single claim of curing myopia true? Baba Ramdev claims to even cure _Cancer_ with yoga. If you want the question to be hyper-specific then you can take my question as _Does Yoga cure myopia without surgery?_

Comment: Make a *reasonable* argument and maybe the community will reopen. Mods are not the ultimate judges of what stays open or closed, and are allowed an opinion just like any other community member. At the moment there are no reopen votes here, so I'd start by assuming there are issues, not that Oddthinking did not read the question correctly, for example.

Comment: @Sklivvz _Mods are not the ultimate judges_. Then why did the moderator _unilaterally_ closed my question? Let the community decide what to close and what to open. Open the question and if 5 close voters decide to close it then I'll happy to delete the question and go away. Why do the other way around?

Comment: Ghuse jamman kanda kamban.

Comment: @user31782 on the stackexchange platform, including this site, mods are allowed to vote like any other member with enough reputation, their vote is heavier because we trust them more, not because we expect them to abstain from voting.

Comment: Ok. But now I've made the question specific. The question is only about Yoga's claim. If my question gets open I'll ask different questions for other claims by Ayurveda, Homeopathy etc to cure myopia.